# ASRock 4Core1600Twins-P35 SATA Error

Tags: motherboard, sata

I have one old ASRock 4Core1600Twins-P35 type motherboard. All the things work fine on it except SATA connectors.

If I connect (to any of the connectors) one SATA HDD the system can't boot. It stops before BIOS and doesn't show anything. I was using this motherboard in the last year and then this problem came.

If I try with an IDE HDD everything's alright, after start BIOS comes and it can boot.
The motherboard has the newest BIOS version (1.60).

The tested SATA HDD is good as well, it's working in other PC at this moment, too.

Does anyone have ideas what this problem could be and maybe some way to fix it if its possible?

Comment: Did the SATA work before the BIOS update?

Comment: Wait... can you describe what are you doing? Are you trying to connect both the SATA with the IDE/PATA drive? If the SATA drive has no OS, then if I recall ASRock motherboards default to SATA, so it might be a question of acessing the BIOS and setting the IDE as default.

Comment: The old pc was useing with this mobo + a SATA HDD + IDE DVD-RW.The BIOS was 1.6 since I have it,and I didn't update it.SATA HDD has os,and if I try to connect only that without still I get the same result: after start boot failed,and it can't go to BIOS and load os.

Comment: First, some clarification. What you are referring as BIOS (Basic Input and Output System) is actually the POST (Power On Self Test), where the PC displays the information needed to start the computer. No sort of information appears whatsoever if you try to run with the SATA alone?

Comment: After start nothing apear on screen with SATA HDD.The screen doesn't come which display some info about the PC(CPU,mobo and other stuff) and can't get into BIOS.Sorry ,I hope now its clear.

Comment: It is. With the IDE and SATA drive both installed, can you press F11 and select the SATA drive to boot from?

Comment: For reference here's the [motherboard manual link](ftp://europe.asrock.com/manual/4Core1600Twins-P35.pdf)

Comment: OMG,this motherboard wasn't in use since weeks,but today I did a try.I put into 2 SATA HDD + 1 IDE DVD drive and everything were running fine:O I dont know what happend.Long time ago the problem came when we were trying a bad VGA,and after that the system couldn't boot in.After changing back the good VGA the problem was there yet.Maybe that VGA caused something,but now the pc runs yet.When the problem was here I wasn't able to choose any,and I didn't get reaction for any button on keyboard.Thanks that you were trying to help,it fixed itself :D I hope :D

Comment: I'm still not happy about this situation, but feel free to add an answer to your question, as to help others that might have the same problem.

Comment: It still annoying me too,that I don't know the reason why I met with that problem.But on the other hand I was happy cause it works again.

Comment: It might be anything... and that's what bothers me. Still, I gave you several pointers and the manual does have some pages on setting up SATA drivers, including pin settings.